# Inverse Fourier transform of modified Bessel function (part II)

Tags: fourier-analysis, special-functions, fourier-transform, bessel-functions

I'm relatively new to Fourier transforms so apologize in advance if this problem seems trivial.

In order to solve a second order PDE I have defined the following sine Fourier transform

$$E(r,\lambda)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\eta(r,z)\cos(\lambda z)\,\textrm{d}z.$$

By doing so I arrive at the following solution for $E$ (which I know is correct)

$$E(r,\lambda)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{\lambda}\left\{-\frac{rI_{0}(\lambda r)}{I_{1}(\lambda)}+\frac{I_{1}(\lambda)I_{1}(\lambda r)}{2I_{0}(\lambda)I_{1}(\lambda)-\lambda[I_{0}^{2}(\lambda)-I_{1}^{2}(\lambda)]}\right\},$$

where $I_{\alpha}$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

My goal is to invert the Fourier transform and obtain the solution for $\eta$. So far I have that

\begin{align*}
\eta(r,z)&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}E(r,\lambda)\cos(\lambda z)\,\textrm{d}\lambda
\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left\{-\frac{rI_{0}(\lambda r)}{I_{1}(\lambda)}+\frac{I_{1}(\lambda)I_{1}(\lambda r)}{2I_{0}(\lambda)I_{1}(\lambda)-\lambda[I_{0}^{2}(\lambda)-I_{1}^{2}(\lambda)]}\right\}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\lambda}\,\textrm{d}\lambda.
\end{align*}

This looks horrible so, to start, I've decided to focus on the first part of this integral

$$F_{1}=-\frac{r}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{I_{0}(\lambda r)}{I_{1}(\lambda)}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\lambda}\,\textrm{d}\lambda.$$

Using Erdelyi's 'Higher Transcendental Functions' I have the following

\begin{align*}
F_{1}&=-\frac{r}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{I_{0}(\lambda r)}{I_{1}(\lambda)}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\lambda}\,\textrm{d}\lambda
\\
&=-\frac{r}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{J_{0}(\textrm{i}\lambda r)}{J_{1}(\textrm{i}\lambda)}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\lambda}\,\textrm{d}\lambda
\\
&=\frac{r}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{J_{2}(\textrm{i}\lambda r)}{J_{1}(\textrm{i}\lambda)}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\lambda}\,\textrm{d}\lambda+\frac{2\textrm{i}}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{J_{1}(\textrm{i}\lambda r)}{J_{1}(\textrm{i}\lambda)}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\lambda^{2}}\,\textrm{d}\lambda
\\
&=\frac{2\textrm{i}r}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{J_{2}(\beta_{n}r)}{(\beta_{n}^{2}+\lambda^{2})J_{2}(\beta_{n})}\cos(\lambda z)\,\textrm{d}\lambda
\\
&\quad+\frac{4\textrm{i}}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{J_{1}(\beta_{n}r)}{\beta_{n}J_{2}(\beta_{n})}-\frac{\lambda^{2}J_{1}(\beta_{n}r)}{\beta_{n}(\beta_{n}^{2}+\lambda^{2})J_{2}(\beta_{n})}\right]\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\lambda^{2}}\,\textrm{d}\lambda
\\
&=\frac{2\textrm{i}r}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{J_{2}(\beta_{n}r)}{J_{2}(\beta_{n})}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\beta_{n}^{2}+\lambda^{2}}\,\textrm{d}\lambda
\\
&\quad+\frac{4\textrm{i}}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{J_{1}(\beta_{n}r)}{\beta_{n}J_{2}(\beta_{n})}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\lambda^{2}}\,\textrm{d}\lambda-\frac{4\textrm{i}}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{J_{1}(\beta_{n}r)}{\beta_{n}J_{2}(\beta_{n})}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\beta_{n}^{2}+\lambda^{2}}\,\textrm{d}\lambda
\\
&=-\frac{2\textrm{i}r}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{J_{0}(\beta_{n}r)}{J_{2}(\beta_{n})}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\beta_{n}^{2}+\lambda^{2}}\,\textrm{d}\lambda
+\frac{2\textrm{i}r}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\lambda^{2}}\,\textrm{d}\lambda
\\
&=\textrm{i}r\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{J_{0}(\beta_{n}r)e^{-\beta_{n}z}}{\beta_{n}J_{0}(\beta_{n})}+\frac{2\textrm{i}r}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\lambda^{2}}\,\textrm{d}\lambda
\end{align*}

The quoted solution I'm working towards is

$$\eta=-r\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{J_{0}(\beta_{n}r)e^{-\beta_{n}z}}{\beta_{n}J_{0}(\beta_{n})}+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{R}\left[\textrm{i}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{I_{1}(k_{m})I_{1}(rk_{m})e^{\textrm{i}k_{m}z}}{k_{m}I_{1}^{2}(k_{m})}\right],$$

where $k_{m}$ are the zeros of $2I_{0}(k)I_{1}(k)-k[I_{0}^{2}(k)-I_{1}^{2}(k)]$. I'm assuming that the first part of this solution comes from the first part of the integral that I have defined. I can see that I'm relatively close to the first part of the quoted solution but must be making some mistakes along the way.

One big problem is the

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\lambda z)}{\lambda^{2}}\,\textrm{d}\lambda,$$

term that I've got - this integral doesn't converge!

Can anyone offer any help and advice?

Much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: $F_1$ does not converge as the function to integrate is $\sim \lambda^{-2}$ near $\lambda=0$. You cannot separate $\eta(r,z)$ as a sum like that.

Comment: So my assumption that the first part of the solution comes solely from the first part of my expression for $E(r, \lambda)$ is incorrect? 
i.e., $F_{2}$ must also contribute to the first part of the solution for $\eta(r, z)$?

Comment: You write "I have defined the following sine Fourier transform" and then you define a cosine transform? The problem is the choice to choose the sine or cosine transform is dictated with the boundary conditions. Maybe you made a wrong choice? Without knowing what problem you are solving it is not possible to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that was simply a typo - should be 'cosine' transform. The boundary conditions dictate that this must be a cosine transformation.